# Instruction operands must be of the same size error

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I have defined the array in data segment like - `myArray    byte  01,  03,  02,  05`
In the code I have a line  `mov eax, BYTE PTR myArray[ecx]` the assembler throws a build error here 
instruction operands must be of the same size
What could be the reason for this. How do I fix this. I want to loop over this array and print it's
elements

```
TITLE Subtract Two Nums (SubTwoNums.asm)
; This program collects two numbers and subtracts the second from the first
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
prompt BYTE "Please enter a number: ", 0
data byte 0A9h
fib  dword 01030205h
msg byte ", " , 0
dwordzeros DWORD 000000h
myArray dword  01,  03,  02,  05

.code

main PROC

mov eax, 0
mov ecx, 0

loop_start:
  cmp ecx, 3
  jge loop_end
  mov eax, myArray[ecx]
  call WriteDec
  mov edx, offset  msg
  call WriteString
  add ecx, 1
  jmp loop_start
loop_end:
exit
```

main ENDP
END main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eax` is 32 bits, while the value from `BYTE PTR myArray[ecx]` is 8 bits. Depending on what you're trying to achieve, there are several possible solutions. Among them are

You can move the byte value into a temporary 32 bit register:

```
movzx ebx,BYTE PTR myArray[ecx]
add eax,ebx
```

You can accumulate the sum as an 8 bit value:

```
add al,BYTE PTR myArray[ecx]
```

You can change the type of `myArray` from `byte` to `dword`.

Comment: Thanks. It didn't throw the compile error. But when I am looping over the array it does print the first value correctly but the rest values are some random numbers.
  Before the start of the loop I have `mov eax, 0` inside the loop : `mov eax, myArray[ecx] ` `call WriteDec` `add ecx, 1` It does print the 01 but after that it prints a value like `50331648`

Comment: @ishita As I've made an (incorrect) assumption about what your problem is, edit your question to include a [mre] so that it is clear what the problem is that you're having.

Comment: I have updated the full code. I think I mistakenly put `add` there whereas I just wanted to print out the numbers in the array

Comment: @ishita: Your question still says you have a `byte` array, but now the code you posted has `myArray dword  01,  03,  02,  05`.  And you only increment ECX by 1, so you're taking a misaligned 4-byte window that was bytes from two different array elements.

Answer (score 1):

It's just the way the opcodes are designed.  For most of them there's two forms: operand size "always bytes", and operand size "processor state".  The latter depends on execution mode, segment descriptors, and whether the "non-default" size has been specified (prefix bytes toggle individual instructions).

To move smaller data into a larger register, you must use an appropriately sized source (ie BYTE PTR for memory load, as you have done, but `cl` to move from `ecx` itself), and either load it similarly into the appropriate smaller destination, or use an instruction that does the conversion explicitely (such as `movzx` or `movsx`; move-with-zero-extend/sign-extend, respectively).  Unless you are deliberately preserving upper bytes in the destination, prefer the latter.

Also be aware that, any load or alu result into a 32-bit register always clears the upper half of that register's 64-bit form, but the opposite happens for other combinations of sizes.